# Pygame make pixel opposite of pixel below it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyautogui

I am making a desktop assistant using pygame, and overlaying him on the screen. Since he is only black, it makes it hard to see him when the backgrounds on the pc are black.

I would like him to have the opposite color of whatever pixels are below him.

I have already found a way to get the color of the pixels in a position on the screen ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162960/20409816) but I don't know how I can get the exact positions of the pixels in the image I am displaying, or change specific pixels in my image.
(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so sorry for the bare links)

Normal assistant:
[image: The desktop assistant]

Hard to see assistant:
[image: The desktop assistant but hard to see because he blends into the background]

Comment: It might be better to give your assistant a white shadow to make it visible on different surfaces. You could look at articles on how to improve subtitle readability ([e.g.](https://documentarycameras.com/10-ways-make-subtitle-styles-readable/)).

Comment: Glad that helped, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future knowledge seekers.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a white outline to the stick figure:
[Stick figure with a small single pixel white outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uZfl.png)